# Angular 6 - Cannot read property 'outlets' of null

Tags: angular, angular6

I am working on **angular 6**, when I add a router link without any condition (`*ngIf`) the router link throws "`Cannot read property 'outlets' of null`" but when I add a condition within the particular section it won't throw any error link that.

Example :

```
<section>
<a [routerLink]="['/user',x?.username]"> {{x?.username}} </a>
</section>
```

the above code throws an error. (Cannot read property 'outlets' of null)
but

```
<section *ngIf="x?.username != null">
<a [routerLink]="['/user',x?.username]"> {{x?.username}} </a>
</section>
```

this one won't throw any error.

Could any one guide me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error occurs when [routerLink] receives a null.
You can put the ngIf to avoid the error.

Answer (score 4):

This error may be thrown when a `routerLink`, e.g. a route contains a `null` value.

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot read property 'outlets' of null

The error message is very clear. Probably the `x?.username` comes from an async call so you have to wait for it to be set and then deal with in the view. This what you're doing with the condition `*ngIf="x?.username != null"`. Here you're waiting for username to defined or set to show the link